# Assigning Variables in Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Is it possible to assign a variable to CurrentItem in a workflow? I would like to increment that variable each day in order to do a task once it hits a certain number.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to the list and check that column's value everytime the workflow runs.  The workflow variables are not persisted between runs, so you have to use something in the list item.